# Can't access the get method from expression language in jsf

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I can't access getCpuUsage() method from my xhtml code via

```
<h:outputText id="cpu_usage"
                    value="#{cpuUsageBean.cpuUsage} %" />
```

When i add @bean annotation to  my getCpuUsage() method this method works when component initialized.But after  that when i try to access via xhtml file seen on the page nothing happened at all. I hope you understand me well . Thanks in advance

my xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body style="margin-left:50px">
    <h2>PrimeFaces Polling Example</h2>
    <h:form>
        CPU usage:
        <b> <h:outputText id="cpu_usage"
                value="#{cpuUsageBean.cpuUsage} %" />
        </b>
    <p:poll interval="1" update="cpu_usage" /> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

MY MANAGED BEAN SO COMPONENT:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


@Component
@Scope("VIEW")
//@ViewScoped
//@Named
@Slf4j
public class CpuUsageBean {

    private AtomicInteger cpuUsage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cpuUsage = new AtomicInteger(50);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        es.execute(() -> {
            while (true) {
                // simulating cpu usage
                int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10, 11);
                int usage = cpuUsage.get();
                usage += i;
                if (usage < 0) {
                    usage = 0;
                } else if (usage > 100) {
                    usage = 100;
                }
                cpuUsage.set(usage);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public int getCpuUsage() {
        System.out.println("-----getCpuUsage : " + cpuUsage);
        log.error("---------- getCpuUsage calisti");
        return cpuUsage.get();
    }
}
```

MY SPRİNGBOOT APP CLASS :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tutorial.PrimeFacesTutorial.controller,com.tutorial.PrimeFacesTutorial")
    public class PrimeFacesTutorialApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(PrimeFacesTutorialApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Without polling it works? Any errors?

Comment: yes unfortunately. when i treat getCpuUsage() method as bean it shows " java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find backup for factory " error . But if i remove bean annotation no errors showing around. But as i said can't access the getCpuUsage() method via netither #{] language nor ${} . I tried web.xml or faces.config tricks on the net But noone of them fixed my issue.

Comment: Why is this error missing in the question? Did you try putting this error in a search engine? lpts of Q/A in stackoverflow on this

Comment: yea i did . I know there are duplicate questions for that . I saw your comments either. But as i said noone of them worked with @ bean annotation . My problem not related with @ bean . my problem is can't access properties from xhtml so xhtml not rendering properly .

Comment: Are you using JoinFaces?  If not I think you need to to make Spring Boot + JSF work properly.  Because I am looking at your annotations and they are wrong.  See http://joinfaces.org/